# manipulating the list of list in python and make a new one

Tags: python, list

I have 2 big list of lists like these 2 example (big and small):

```
big = [['chr1', 'ENSEMBL', 'exon', '12595', '12721', '.', '+', '.', 'gene_id', '"ENSG00000223972.4";', 'transcript_id', '"ENST00000518655.2";', 'gene_type', '"pseudogene";', 'gene_status', '"KNOWN";', 'gene_name', '"DDX11L1";'], ['chr1', 'ENSEMBL', 'exon', '13403', '13655', '.', '+', '.', 'gene_id', '"ENSG00000223972.4";', 'transcript_id', '"ENST00000518655.2";', 'gene_type', '"pseudogene";', 'gene_status', '"KNOWN";', 'gene_name', '"ACAD9";']]


small = [['ACAD9', 'ENSG00000177646', '372', '503', '0.0010154314', '0.0081838994', '0.4251428571', 'YES\n'], ['ACIN1', 'ENSG00000100813', '167', '647', '8.59E-33', '1.80E-31', '0.2051597052', 'YES\n']]
```

I want to make a list of lists from `big` and `small`. in fact if the 1st item in the `inner list` of `small` is equal to the `18th item` in the `inner list` of `big`, i want to make a new `list of lists` in which the `inner list` would have `1st and 2nd` items of `inner list` from `small` and `1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th, 5th and 18th` items of `inner list` from `big`.

here is the expected output:

expected output:

```
out = [['ACAD9', 'ENSG00000177646', 'chr1', 'ENSEMBL', 'exon', '13403', '13655', '"ACAD9";']]
```

for this goal I wrote the following code but it does not return the expected output. do you know how to fix it?

```
final = []
for i in range(0, len(eg)):
    for j in range(0, len(gt)):
        gtf_row = gt[j]
        esse_gene_row = eg[i]
        gtf_column = gtf_row.split()
        esse_gene_column = esse_gene_row.split()
        gtf_symbol = gtf_columns[17]
        esse_gene_symbol = esse_gene_columns[0]
        if gtf_symbol == esse_gene_symbol:
            final.append(gt(j))
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `in`, given that the two strings are different, but the one from `small` is a substring of the one from `big`. For selecting the items on each list I suggest you use [itemgetter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter):

```
from operator import itemgetter

select_from_small = itemgetter(0, 1)
select_from_big = itemgetter(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 17)

big = [['chr1', 'ENSEMBL', 'exon', '12595', '12721', '.', '+', '.', 'gene_id', '"ENSG00000223972.4";', 'transcript_id',
        '"ENST00000518655.2";', 'gene_type', '"pseudogene";', 'gene_status', '"KNOWN";', 'gene_name', '"DDX11L1";'],
       ['chr1', 'ENSEMBL', 'exon', '13403', '13655', '.', '+', '.', 'gene_id', '"ENSG00000223972.4";', 'transcript_id',
        '"ENST00000518655.2";', 'gene_type', '"pseudogene";', 'gene_status', '"KNOWN";', 'gene_name', '"ACAD9";']]

small = [['ACAD9', 'ENSG00000177646', '372', '503', '0.0010154314', '0.0081838994', '0.4251428571', 'YES\n'],
         ['ACIN1', 'ENSG00000100813', '167', '647', '8.59E-33', '1.80E-31', '0.2051597052', 'YES\n']]

out = []
for s in small:
    for b in big:
        if s[0] in b[17]:
            out.append(list(select_from_small(s)) + list(select_from_big(b)))

print(out)
```

**Output**

```
[['ACAD9', 'ENSG00000177646', 'chr1', 'ENSEMBL', 'exon', '13403', '13655', '"ACAD9";']]
```

A more *pythonic* way of writing the code above will be to use the following [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
out = [list(select_from_small(s) + select_from_big(b)) for s in small for b in big if s[0] in b[17]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a `list` comprehension that iterates over `big` and `small`

```
In [12]: [s[:2] + b[:5] + [b[-1]] for s in small for b in big if s[0] in b[-1]]
Out[12]: 
[['ACAD9',
  'ENSG00000177646',
  'chr1',
  'ENSEMBL',
  'exon',
  '13403',
  '13655',
  '"ACAD9";']]
```